# Solving for X given two matrices that equal its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know $A \cdot A^{-1} = I$, but I am not sure how to begin this question:

Solve for $X$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ -6 & 6 \end{pmatrix}-X\begin{pmatrix} 7 & -8 \\ 7 & -7 \end{pmatrix}=I
$$

Comment: Could you make the image smaller, or, better yet, retype it in $\LaTeX$? It takes half of my screen.

Comment: Sorry, my screen is retina, so it has larger resolution.

Comment: Hooray for $\LaTeX$!!!

Answer (score 2):

$$A-XB=I$$
$$XB=A-I$$
$$X=(A-I)B^{-1}=AB^{-1}-B^{-1}$$

Comment: Perfect, makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: I understand, thanks. It must stay in the exact order.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the type $A - XB = I$.

My hint is: If $A$ and $B$ were real numbers, how would you solve the equation $a - bx = 1$ for $x\in\mathbb R$?